# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x \to \pi} \frac{(\pi -x)\sin x}{1 + \cos x}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

My sister is a $11$'th grade student and she is preparing for a Calculus test paper. This was in last year's sample exam :
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \pi} \frac{(\pi -x)\sin x}{1 + \cos x}$$

She asked for my help but really gave me some really crippling conditions.
The solution is quite easy to reach if one uses L'Hospital, Taylor series, or a really  plain $y - \pi= x$ substitution.

But they weren't even taught substitutions yet ! So, how would you go about this ? Maybe some clever trigonometric massaging?

A basic manipulations yields:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \pi} \frac{(\pi -x)\sin x}{1 + \cos x} = \lim\limits_{x \to \pi} (\pi - x ) \tan\bigg(\frac{x}{2}\bigg)$$

Any ideas?

Comment: Does she know $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\sin x}=1$?$$\dfrac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}=\dfrac{1+\cos x}{\sin x}$$Then $\sin x=\sin(\pi-x)$, etc

Comment: Just asked her, that can be used. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

1) Multiply numerator and denominator of the fraction by $(1-\cos x)$ and note that $1-\cos^2 x=\sin^2 x $.

2) use $ \sin x=\sin(\pi-x)$

3) use the special limit $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
&\lim\limits_{x \to \pi} \frac{(\pi -x)\sin x}{1 + \cos x}\\
=&\lim\limits_{x \to \pi} \frac{-\sin x}{\frac{\cos x-(-1)}{x-\pi}}\\
=&\lim\limits_{x \to \pi} \frac{-\sin x}{\frac{\cos x-\cos \pi}{x-\pi}}\\
=&\lim\limits_{x \to \pi} \frac{-\sin x}{\cos' \pi}\\
=&\lim\limits_{x \to \pi} \frac{-\sin x}{-\sin \pi}\\
=&\frac{\sin \pi}{\sin \pi}\\
=&1\\
\end{align}

Comment: The answer should be $2$, can't see where your mistake is.

Comment: You have $\sin(\pi)$, which is to say *zero*, in the denominator of something.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'm also puzzled..

Comment: @Ian You're right.

Comment: What you did before replacing $\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(\pi)}{x-\pi}$ with $\cos'(\pi)$ is fine. It's just that to get the answer by this method, you need to somehow know "second order" information about sine and cosine...which falls under the category of things that the OP says you're not allowed to use.

Comment: @Ian Okay, thanks. I'll delete this answer.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Check the solution and do tell in case of any doubt.

Comment: Where did you get the image from?

Comment: @egreg I typed it on my editor.

Answer (score 0):

Use

$$\frac{(\pi -x)\sin x}{1 + \cos x}=(\pi-x)\frac{2\sin\left(\frac x2\right)\cos\left(\frac x2\right)}{\cos^2\left(\frac x2\right)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Set $\theta =\pi -x \iff x=\pi-\theta$. Then
$$\frac{(\pi-x)\sin x}{1+\cos x}=\frac{\theta\sin \theta}{1-\cos \theta}\sim_0\frac{\theta^2}{\dfrac{\theta^2}2}=2.$$
Thus the limit is $\color{red}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\pi}\dfrac{(\pi-x)\sin x}{1+\cos x}=\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{y\sin(\pi-y)}{1+\cos(\pi-y)}=\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{y\sin y}{1-\cos y}=\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{2y\sin {\dfrac y2}\cos {\dfrac y2}}{2\sin^2 {\dfrac y2}}=\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow 0}\left(\dfrac {\sin {\dfrac y2}}y\right)^{-1}\dot\cos{\dfrac y2}=1.$